# Heat Capacity versus Fourier's Law

Tags: thermodynamics

What came first, Fourier's Law, or the definition of heat capacity?

Comment: Can you please provide some context on your motivation for asking this question?

Comment: I am just a bit curious about the history of the thermodynamics.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of physics not physics

Comment: What's "Fourier Law"? Is not is the same as "Newton's law of cooling"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning -- assumptions made in the following.

Fourier's Wiki page mentions that

> In 1822 Fourier published his work on heat flow in Théorie analytique
>   de la chaleur (The Analytical Theory of Heat)
>   Which one could interpret as the first publication of what later became named "Fourier's Law."

Whereas the Wiki page on *heat capacity*  states

> In a previous theory of heat common in the early modern period, heat
>   was thought to be a measurement of an invisible fluid, known as the
>   caloric. Bodies were capable of holding a certain amount of this
>   fluid, hence the term heat capacity, named and first investigated by
>   Scottish chemist Joseph Black in the 1750s.

Thus  one can assume (making an ass of you and me) or [assert](https://xkcd.com/1339/) (see the title-text)  that heat capacity was defined first.

Comment: Interesting. 70 years is quite a long time between the development of the heat capacity idea and Fourier's Law.